# Keg not carbonating.

Tags: carbonation, kegging, force-carbonation

5 gal keg ball lock. In a keezer at 35 deg. 30psi for three days then set it down to 13-14 psi for two days I have an 8ft line. Beer is dispensing great taste awesome but there is little to no carbonation. I should be getting a CO2 vol of 2.6. Anyone have any ideas what going on? And I did a leak check I don't have any and the CO2 tank is new first time filled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just need more time.  I usually let mine go for 7-10 days total before.
5 days seems a little short to me even with your 30PSI upfront charge.

Comment: Ok I'll give it more time, thank you very much!

Comment: time is all it took, thank you very much brewchez.

Comment: Great.  I hate struggling with my kegorator but its nice when it all works out.

Comment: SSOOOOOO much better than bottling!